# PHP $_GET['Variable'] Echos but Doesn't Evaluate In a $query

Tags: php, mysql

Snippets of what I have:

```
echo $_GET['tournamententryid'].'<br/>';
```

The above line will correctly display: 32

Just below the line above, I have:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $query='UPDATE tbl_tournamententry set score='.$_POST['score'].' WHERE id='.$_GET['tournamententryid'];
    echo $query;
}
```

The output of the 'echo $query' from just above results in this:

```
UPDATE tbl_tournamententry set score=876 WHERE id=
```

I cannot understand why the $query variable does not include the . . .id=32.  The $query I'm trying to concatenate together should read:

```
UPDATE tbl_tournamententry set score=876 WHERE id=32
```

What am I missing?

More information:
The receiving page URL is: 
    http://example.com/test/submitascore.php?tournamententryid=32&gamename=Creature+From+the+Black+Lagoon

That URL is where the 'get' of my $_GET['tournamententryid'] value of 32 (and it properly echos) comes from.  The $_POST receives the score that the user entered.  So, Page 1 allowed the user to select the 'tournamententryid' which was a href to the submitascore.php page.  The submitascore.php URL includes the $_GET variable

Comment: I see `$_GET` then I see `$_POST['submit']`, *hm*.

Comment: i see SQL injection attacks in for future

Comment: The $_GET['tournamentid'] is passed to the current page via a GET URL.  In the page form (POST), the user enters a score in an input="text" and clicks the SUBMIT button for the form to process.  The query should take the tournamentid value that was passed to the form to use to indicate the database record being updated with the new score.

Comment: try a var_dump($_GET) after that line

Comment: You are using `mysqli_query()`, correct? There isn't enough code to give you a definite answer, nor do we know which API you're connecting with, including what your form holds. Check for errors.

Comment: I understand the security issues - right now I'm brute-force learning PHP/HTML as I leave my native Win32 experience.  My first goal is just to make it work and later rewrite with better practices.

Comment: @Fred-ii- -- Yes, mysqli_query() will follow - snipped to be concise as possible

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`. I think it may just be quotes issue.

Comment: @the_nuts -- echo var_dump($_GET) yields:  array(0) { }  ---  Best I can tell, the $_GET['tournamentid'] loses globality when in the if (isset($_POST section

Comment: If it loses globality, then it's probably a scope issue. Are you using any functions at all?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am not using functions.  Using your first two 'error reporting' features I get:  **Notice: Undefined index: tournamententryid in /test/submitascore.php on line 31** -- (and line 36 where I use it in the $query).  Line 31 is the echo $_GET['tournamentid'] which correctly displays the value.  Line 36 is where it is ignored.  After adding the error reporting, line 31 doesn't echo the value.

Comment: $_GET is a superglobal variable, it can never lose globality... maybe you make a redirect or your url is malformed?

Comment: @the_nuts -- my URL is http://example.com/test/submitascore.php?tournamententryid=32&gamename=Creature+From+the+Black+Lagoon - and the echo correctly displays '32' while just 2 lines later it is no longer accessible or null

Comment: So strange then... I've tried on my machine and it's working: http://i.imgur.com/NXjTJS6.png

Answer (score 2):

This is a TERRIBLE practice. Look into sanitizing your variables before injecting them into SQL.

This code below is vulnerable to SQL Injection (attacks)

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $query='UPDATE tbl_tournamententry set score='.$_POST['score'].' WHERE id='.$_GET['tournamententryid'];
    echo $query;
}
```

Look into PDO & ensure you're not using an outdated version of PHP

PDO example

firstly connect to your database like so

```
$database = "mydatabase";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";

$PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
```

Then

```
$sql = $PDO->prepare('UPDATE tbl_tournamententry set score=:score WHERE id=:id');
$sql->execute(array(
    ":score" => $_POST['score'],
    ":id" => $_GET['tournamententryid'],
);
```

using prepared statements, your variables will be sanitized to prevent SQL injection.
By putting a variable straight into SQL that users have control of, anyone can put anything there. SQL is separate to PHP.

if for example `$_GET['id']` was set by the user as `'' or 1=1`
with an SQL statement like

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$_GET['id']`

it would then be `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='' or 1=1`
SQL is capable of mathematics, therefore 1 DOES EQUAL 1 and ALWAYS will.

In more simple terms, this means `IF 1=1 LIST ALL USERS`

Additionally, you're using $_POST and $_GET

$_GET comes from the URL e.g.

`http://example.com/?tournamententryid=1`

`$_GET['tournamententryid']` will be able to access that in the URL above. This is known as the GET Method.

Whereas, `$_POST['tournamententryid']` is a different variable sent through the POST Method. They server different purposes. You may want `$_POST['tournamententryid']`

Answer (score 2):

I understand the problem:

When the page loads, the URL correctly contains the GET tournamententryid variable and $_GET['tournamententryid'] is available.

The page contains a form method="post" which calls itself, so when the user clicks the submit button, the URL gets re-written from:

```
http://example.com/test/submitascore.php?tournamententryid=32&gamename=Creature+From+the+Black+Lagoon
```

to

```
http://example.com/test/submitascore.php
```

thereby deleting the $_GET variables entirely.  Thank you to all for the brain exercise!

Solution:  In the form method="post", store the value of $_GET['tournamententryid'] in an input="hidden" value=$_GET['tournamententryid'] for use in the POST section